# How to improve the performance and response time of Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I discovered Plotly for plotting candlestick chart and I tried to use it for plotting SPX 1 mins chart. I noticed extremely slow response time of the output graph (label pop up and zoom-in/out, etc) when trying to feed a whole year of 1-min OHLC data into (over 300k rows).

I just used the example code from Plotly website cause I am not a programmer,

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file:///Users/jacliu2/Downloads/DAT_XLSX_SPXUSD_M1_2021.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['SPX.Open'], high=df['SPX.High'],
                low=df['SPX.Low'], close=df['SPX.Close'])
                     ])

fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

Is there any way to improve the performance and response time of Plotly so I can use it to plot 1-min candlestick graph for 1 year time frame?

Or how can I get the code to allow me to select specific date/time so Plotly can plot specific time frame only to avoid such lagging when it trying to plot a whole year in one go?

Comment: You say you want to specify a specific date and time, but what exactly do you want to extract? Before that, there is an example in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#time-series-with-range-selector-buttons) of a time-series axis button that can be used as a visualization aid.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!
Since I feed a whole year of data into the Pandas, and this cause Plotly become super unresponsive. I thought may be making Plot to display a menu to allow me to input a specific time frame to display first in order to improve the situation, instead of asking Plotly to plot all data into a graph in one go.

Comment: In plotly, user input is rarely used, and buttons and dropdowns are usually created in advance and then selected by the user. Also, you turned off the slider function, but it is a way for the user to select a time period, so I guess it is true.

Comment: I did tried to add back the slider function but the page response time is just unbearable. That's why I want to see if there is any way to improve the response time to a level that I can use the slider and also the candlestick graph can pop up information when I hover the mouse cursor over any candle in the graph.

Comment: Hey, I might be a little late to the party but I think this is what you need https://github.com/predict-idlab/plotly-resampler and I'd suggest using .to_numpy() on your variables as it speeds up the figure creation

Answer (score 2):

All of the data is stored inside the html/javascript the moment you pass the `df` to `fig` so the responsiveness is going to be limited by the size of the df unfortunately.

To be honest, I don't think this will lead to much an improvement in response time, but you can try downsizing the df if you are okay with reducing the precision of the floats in the plot. 300k rows with four different values is a lot for the plotly renderer to handle.

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for the reply! By downsizing the df you mean reduce the number of row that I try to feed into Plotly, right? Like splitting it into 2-months x 6 files. If that's ok to me, is there a way to make Plotly to let me select which 2-months time frame to display by using a drop-down menu (or something like that)? Thanks again!

Comment: @Jacky I mean downsizing each column from, say, float64 to float32 if possible. There are some tips [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-save-memory-with-these-simple-tricks-943841f8c32)

Comment: Hi Derek, I tried it last night. Changed to float32 or even float 16 not able to help alot. The situation did improved for abit but still very unresponsive. I guess that's really a limitation when the quantity of the data reach to a certain level. Thanks alot still for your reply!